# Loose Cassette - Any Ideas?

Tags: cassette

I have a loose cassette but the only the top is loose.
I took the wheel off and tightened it but it has made no difference?
The top 3 or 4 cogs move freely when I hold the cranks so they don't move.
Any ideas?

Comment: Clarifying - the 3 or 4 biggest cogs in your cassette are wiggling freely around the axle, or side to side ?   Do you have a lockring tool, a big spanner, and a chain whip to remove the cassette from the freehub and inspect?  Photos would help.

Comment: They move side to side a bit, not forwards or backwards.

Comment: I took the cassette off, cleaned and put it back on but it is still moving.

Comment: Maybe you need spacers? Is the lockring properly pressing against the cassette?

Comment: We're now living in a world where you really need to say what kind of freehub body and cassette are in question, since XD and Microspline each have some of their own things that can go wrong and cause this problem, but writing an answer that covers all of it is probably overkill.

Comment: @NathanKnutson I’d be a little surprised if a GX or higher cassette was behaving like this :D

Comment: @MaplePanda Yes but XD cassettes getting installed without spacers on XDR and misbehaving is now a thing, and also XD in general has a very fine thread that can tend to be kinda frictiony and weird feeling so just undertightening it is also possible. Not saying either are likely.

Comment: @michael concur- could you add that as an answer please ?

Comment: @Charlie did you grab any photos ?

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am taking it to the bike shop on Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

How did you end up with that cassette? If you have newly installed it, maybe you're missing a sprocket and/or a spacer. In fact, I would say that that's the most likely scenario, *if* it's a newly installed cassette.

Comment: Hi everyone, fhanks for all the responese, I ended up taking it to the bike shop and turns out that it was pretty tight, just needed another 1/4 turn. Thanks Charlie